# Java expression type

Tags: java, types, expression, theory

I saw a question on Java manuals that keeps grinding my gear so i'm posting it here to solve it once and for all.

The question is:

If n and k are int type then what type would ' n > k && k < 0 ' expression be?

Possible answers : byte, boolean, int, double, won't compile.

Thank you for your advice on it.

Comment: open your favorite IDE and check it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to check is just to print it using for example [Ideone](http://ideone.com). Check [this link](https://ideone.com/TuUs0L) to see a demonstration.

That said, the expression evaluates to a `boolean`. Since `<` and `>` have higher precedence than `&&`, the expression is equivalent to `(n > k) && (k < 0)`, which is a bit easier to interpret.

Comment: https://ideone.com/P57hUQ - Value is "boxed" to java.lang.Boolean, and this would not be the case had it been int, byte, or anything other than a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

**boolean**

This expression is usually used in a condition and return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

It is boolean because : (n > k && k < 0)

- n > k return boolean
- k < 0 return boolean
- boolean && boolean is **boolean**